# Conditionally append a character in select statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

Functionality I'm trying to add to my DB2 stored procedure:

```
    Select a MIN() date from a joined table column.
    IF there was more than one row in this joined table, append a " * " to the date.
```

Thanks, any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Just write the query to take the min of the date, convert the date to a string, and concatenate that string with the following case statement:  (case when count(*) > 1 then ' *' else '' end).  I don't remember the commands offhand for converting dates to string in DB2, so I can't readily provide the SQL.

Comment: I've tried adding an if check to the join. If rows are more than 1, add the character. Would not compile

Comment: @GordonLinoff i think your looking for VARCHAR_FORMAT(<expr>,<FORMAT>)

Comment: Ted, SQL doesn't understand "if".  You need to use a case statement.

Comment: Are you sure this has to be done in the DB layer?  This sounds like a display problem.  I'd actually return the _count_ as a seperate column, then let my final display code do the character concatenation.  And of course you can't do this in the `JOIN` - you'd have to wrap the initial `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which flavor of DB2 is needed nor if any suggestion worked. This works on DB2 for i:

```
SELECT
 T1.joinCol1,
 max( T2.somedateColumn ),
 count( t2.somedateColumn ),
 char(max( T2.somedateColumn )) concat case when count( T2.somedateColumn )>1 then '*' else '' end 
 FROM joinFile1 t1 join joinFile2 t2
           on joinCol1 = joinCol2
 GROUP BY T1.joinCol1
 ORDER BY T1.joinCol1
```

The SQL is fairly generic, so it should translate to many environments and versions.

Substitute table and column names as needed. The COUNT() here actually counts rows from the JOIN rather than the number of times the specific date occurs. If a count of duplicate dates is needed, then some changes to this example are also needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

Say I have result coming as

```
1   Jeff    1
2   Jeff    333
3   Jeff    77
4   Jeff    1
5   Jeff    14
6   Bob     22
7   Bob     4
8   Bob     5
9   Bob     6
```

Here the value 1 is repeated twice(in 3 column)

So, this query gets the count as 2 along with the * concatenated along with it

SELECT A.USER_VAL,
        DECODE(A.CNT, '1', A.CNT, '0', A.CNT, CONCAT(A.CNT, '*')) AS CNT
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT BT.USER_VAL, CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR2(2)) AS CNT
           FROM SO_BUFFER_TABLE_8 BT
          GROUP BY BT.USER_VAL) A